# Child pages not affected by orderby

Tags: wp-query, order, pre-get-posts

My loop won't order the child pages I'm displaying in the order I want them to, neither `ASC` or `DESC`.
I've already seen many other similar issues, but those were resolved with disabling plugins (which I don't have) or removing or adding quotes (which I've checked multiple times).

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_parent' => 'faq',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$x = 0;
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( $args ) );
if($the_query->have_posts()) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while($the_query->have_posts()) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>';
        echo "<input type='checkbox' id='" . $x . "' />";
        echo "<label for='" . $x . "'>" . get_the_title() . "</label>";
        echo "<div class='answer'>";
        echo the_content();
        echo "</div>";
        echo '</li>';
        $x++;
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    echo "Nothing here to see";
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Who can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`post_parent`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) should be the ***ID*** of the post parent, not the slug.

Apart from that, your code should work. If not, look for any `posts_*` filters or `pre_get_posts` actions that might influence your custom query

### EDIT

Something else I have missed, `$args` is already an array, so you do not need to add it another array when calling it.

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( $args ) );
```

should be

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Removing the array around `$args` did it. However, the parent page got displayed to, but changing post_parent to the post id (integer) instead of the slug, removed the parent page from the list. Thank you!

Comment: my pleasure, glad it worked. Enjoy ;-)